# Angular 2: uiRouter get current state params in root component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, restangular

How can i get params in root component? (app.component.ts)

I have such app.component.ts (i'm using Angular/Cli):

...

```
import {Transition} from "@uirouter/angular";
...

export class AppComponent {
  id: any;

  constructor(private trans: Transition) {
    this.id = trans.params().someId;
  }
}
```

but i get:

`ERROR Error: No provider for Transition!`

But if i use the same logic in any inner component (which has route) - everything is fine. What i do wrong?

Also!

I'm using `ngx-restangular`. And i have in `app.module.ts`:

```
// Function for settting the default restangular configuration
export function RestangularConfigFactory (RestangularProvider, authService) {
  RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://api.test.com/v1');

  // This function must return observable
  var refreshAccesstoken = function () {
    // Here you can make action before repeated request
    return authService.functionForTokenUpdate();
  };

  RestangularProvider.addErrorInterceptor((response, subject, responseHandler) => {
    if (response.status === 403) {

      /*Here somehow I need to get route params too, is it possible, and how?*/

      refreshAccesstoken()
      .switchMap(refreshAccesstokenResponse => {
        //If you want to change request or make with it some actions and give the request to the repeatRequest func.
        //Or you can live it empty and request will be the same.

        // update Authorization header
        response.request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + refreshAccesstokenResponse)

        return response.repeatRequest(response.request);
      })
      .subscribe(
        res => responseHandler(res),
        err => subject.error(err)
      );

      return false; // error handled
    }
    return true; // error not handled
  });
}

// AppModule is the main entry point into Angular2 bootstraping process
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [ 
    // Importing RestangularModule and making default configs for restanglar
    RestangularModule.forRoot([authService], RestangularConfigFactory),
  ],
})
```

how i can get there route params as well?

Comment: Please, don't use abstractions where they are not appropriate. If `Slib` is some specific library (perfectScrollbar), state this explicitly, so the answer could be applicable to this particular library. There's nothing in the question that would be generic to JS libraries in whole. *what is the syntax for ... in typeScript* - it is the same as in JavaScript. TS is a superset of JS. And it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: @estus you aren't right, the same construction is used for a lot of libs

Comment: *What* construction?

Comment: @estus someElement = new SomePlugin()

Comment: Yes, it is constructor function call. And it is all the same in JS and TS. But what does it have to do with all that 'update method' stuff? All that `$('#container').perfectScrollbar('update')` and `SLib('update')` are totally different things that are highly specific to particular library. Sorry, it's not clear what you're asking. The question probably makes sense in your head but not for the answerers, making you the only person who can understand and answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1: route to root component

If you currently have in index.html:

```
<root-component></root-component> <!-- has a ui-view inside it -->
```

and

```
bootstrap: RootComponent
```

---

You can switch to bootstrapping a UIView:

```
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

and

```
bootstrap: UIView
```

then route to your root component

```
const rootState = { component: RootComponent }
```

then your root component will be able to inject the initial `Transition`

See the sample app for an example:

https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-angular/blob/e8f8b6aabd6a51bf283103312930ebeff52fe4c3/src/app/app.module.ts#L37

https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-angular/blob/e8f8b6aabd6a51bf283103312930ebeff52fe4c3/src/app/app.states.ts#L7-L18

### Option 2: Use the transition start observable

```
class RootComponent {
  constructor(router: UIRouter) {
    this.subscription = router.globals.start$.subscribe((trans: Transition) => console.log(trans)))
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

### Option 3: Use a transition hook

If you're trying to do some action for the initial transition, do this in a transition hook

```
function configFn(router: UIRouter) {
  router.transitionService.onStart({}, function(trans: Transition) {
    if (trans.$id === 0) {
      return somepromise; // Allows async, etc
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! but the way, how to get in`router.transitionService.onStart({}, function(trans: Transition) {` route name where i'm going to?

Comment: Get it from the transition. `trans.to()`

Comment: Here is the API doc for `Transition` and `Transition.to`: https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html#to

Comment: strange... i'm getting `ObjectUnsubscribedError` when i added such code:
https://pastebin.com/raw/4wQPQLSV

Comment: please check my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359094/angular-4-uirouter-way-to-get-custom-wrappers

Comment: also, are you sure this is a working sample: `export function uiRouterConfigFn(router: UIRouterModule) {
  router.urlService.rules.otherwise({state: 'nonExisting'});
}` ?

Comment: I think it should be `uiRouterConfigFn(router: UIRouter)`

Comment: by the way: `this.subscription = router.globals.start$.subscribe((trans: Transition) => console.log(trans)))` isn't working
check it plz, Property 'start$' does not exist on type 'UIRouterGlobals'

Comment: saying other words: how to show conditionally different components (which are wrappers with own ui-view) using your code #3, becouse now it's showing me subscribe errors

Comment: hey, what about  router.globals.start$.subscribe ?

Comment: The error you mention is a typescript error.  The `@uirouter/rx` package augments the `RouterGlobals` interface and adds `start$`.  If that isn't working, you could always cast the globals as `any`, i.e.: `(router.globals as any).start$.subscribe()`