# Angular 2: NgbModal transclude in view

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap, ng-modal

Let's say i have such modal template:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3 [innerHtml]="header"></h3>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
</div>
```

and i'm calling this modal from another component so:

---

```
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(MobileDropdownModalComponent, {
      keyboard: false,
      backdrop: 'static'
    });

    modalRef.componentInstance.header = this.text;
```

---

How can i put into `NgbModal` html with bindings etc? Into `ng-content`

Comment: For one thing, although I doubt it's related to your issue, you appear to be accessing a private property in the template.

Comment: Must it be this? `<default-wrapper *ngIf="formWrapper"
                 [userId]="userId"></default-wrapper>`

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn depends on a route i'm going to

Comment: Can post your code into plunker, with a dumb userId or whatever information.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Can you give an example of the final result that you want?

Comment: @ConnorsFan i'm trying to put somehow into ng-content html, main problem: this.modalService do not work with ng-content. Is it clear or not?

Comment: NgbModal doesn't support projection in ng-content. You can use ngTemplateOutlet like https://plnkr.co/edit/Txhhutr5iYAiczgB3sC8?p=preview

Comment: Notice that it the same solution as @Julia Passynkova had already proposed

Comment: `NgbModal` takes a `ComponentType` parameter and then dynamically creates the instance of the component. I tried to instantiate the component outside and inject another component to its ng-content, but that is just another instance of the same component. Final words- it is not possible unless you fork the ngbModal and add an additional method which takes `componentRef` instead of `ComponentType`. Refer below the line of code - 
`const contentRef = this._getContentRef(moduleCFR, options.injector || contentInjector, content, activeModal, options);` - refer to the `NgbModalStack` class

Answer (score 4):

You can get a reference to the component instance from NgbModalRef returned by open method and set the binging there.

here is method that open the modal:

```
open() {
   const instance = this.modalService.open(MyComponent).componentInstance;
   instance.name = 'Julia';
 }
```

and here is the component that will be displayed in the modal with one input binding

```
export class MyComponent {
   @Input() name: string;

   constructor() {
   }
 }
```

===

You can pass a templateRef as input as well. Let say the parent component has

```
 <ng-template #tpl>hi there</ng-template>


 export class AppComponent {
   @ViewChild('tpl') tpl: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {
  }

 open() {
    const instance = 
    this.modalService.open(MyComponent).componentInstance;
     instance.tpl = this.tpl;
  }
}
```

and MyComponent:

```
export class MyComponentComponent {
  @Input() tpl;

  constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.tpl);
  }
}
```

Comment: it works for input like value, string etc. But i need a dom! (ng-content)

Comment: by the way, in my question i'm using componentInstance